# Can't import scriptext module in PyS60 2.0 on N95

Tags: python, module, pys60, importerror, n95

When I try and import scriptext on PyS60 version 2.0 on my N95 phone, I get an import error saying that there is no module named scriptext.

How can I work out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:
http://pys60.garage.maemo.org/doc/s60/scriptext.html

> Note: The service is available from
>   'S60 third edition FP2 and later'.

N95 is a 3rd edition FP1 device.

You can adapt your app at runtime according to the availability of this module by putting the import in a try..except block:

```
try:
    import scriptext
except ImportError:
    # Module could not be imported, tell the user to update to a newer device
    # or continue without it if having scriptext is not crucial to your app.
```